# SVN bugtraq properties for BugZilla

Tags: svn, bugzilla

**Bugtraq properties**:

[image]

I am using the above settings to integrate SVN with BugZilla. The commit message should look like this:

```
"Bug 100000:
Description"
```

I need to remove a newline so the whole message is on one line. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter "[Bb][Uu][Gg] (\d+)" in the **Bug-ID expression** text box. **Message pattern** should be empty.